# Introducing the `tricky-example` tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, questions

A lot of people ask questions regarding tricky integrals or limits, and they simply get tagged `calculus` `limit`, or `calculus` `integral`.

Actually what's happening is we're forming a nice bank of tricky questions, often with good solutions.

If we tagged tricky questions with `tricky-questions` then we could easily look through the repository for some nice credit-free problem set exercises (that have solutions!)

Comment: Downvoters, care to voice your opinions via the "comment" feature?

Comment: I personally don't see an actual sense to use this tag, moreover how users should know that this is a tricky question, and not a simple question or an open problem. In fact, I see a lot of newcomers abusing this tag, and a whole lot of unnecessary retagging in the process.

Comment: One problem is that it is completely subjective.  What one person may find "Tricky" another may not.  How do we know if a question is "Tricky"?  What does that even mean? I believe the current tags try to be as concrete as possible.

Comment: I already suffer much when I see people asking questions with titles like "difficult question about..." or "easy question on...". Please don't! :)

Comment: Moreover, it's a meta tag (like e.g. "soft question"), and meta tags are generally discouraged.

Comment: I agree with @Eric, that it is subjective. What about tagging with `exercise`?

Answer (score 5):

This is almost the very definition of a meta-tag, so ... no.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Almost all the arguments against any meta-tag tag apply to this proposed [tricky-questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tricky-questions) tag as well.

> I think the [subjective] tag is useless at best and actively harmful at worst.
>
> Useless, because for all the talk about filtering by or filtering out subjective questions using that tag, it’s a poor tool for the job simply because the criteria for its use are, well, subjective. I can tell you what a poll is, or a FAQ, or a list, or a getting-to-know-you (GTKY) question… But where the border lies for subjective I cannot say.
>
> And harmful, because there are some users who actually believe that, like community wiki, it’s some sort of magic that allows you to ignore the normal posting standards.
>
> It’s been used pejoratively and defensively, without any real consistency, for a long long time now. Time to go.